# What is this on my kitchen chimney and how to remove it

Tags: cleaning, kitchen

Lately there had been much cooking in our kitchen and today I saw [image: this]  ankle It seems like oil droplet but I wonder how they even got there and how do I clean them up so the chimney net is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

those are droplets of cooking oil that have condensed on the metal grille. They come from the smoke that is made while frying food. The best way to remove it is to take down the grille and put it in a dishwashing machine. The dishwashing detergent is designed to dissolve cooking oil deposits.

Comment: But please check the manual first. While _most_ are dishwasher-safe, finding out afterwards that your model wasn’t can be an expensive lesson.

Comment: I never knew oil can go up in smoke and be condensed into liquid, wow! I thought they got sucked by whatever we fry. I don’t have dishwasher, will fairy on sponge will do?

Comment: any sort of strong soap will do, but you'll also need to use very hot water. By the way, in large restaurant kitchens, the stove fans will all have *grease traps* in them which condense the oil out of the cooking smoke by using perforated aluminum screens which are removed and washed out when they get loaded with grease. I have one in my kitchen too!

Comment: so this means my kitchen doesn't or does it?

Comment: that screen probably *is* the grease trap for your stove fan.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to throw it in your dishwasher, you can try soaking it in a tub full of soapy water for a while then scrubbing. That's what we do. We also have, in the past, soaked in vinegar. Soap works better for us.

Comment: It is sticky after washing.

Comment: Use washing-up liquid (fairy?) direct on the item and dip in hot water in between scrubbing.